# Multiple Rows in one row in SQL without XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have to show some date of a same buying item in a list from one Goods in one row.

The query is like this:

```
SELECT Fname, SUM(Fcount) AS GoodsCount, (Dates?)
FROM FoodSara_tbl T1
GROUP BY Fname, FID
```

The input:

| Fname | GoodsCount | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cake | 2 | 2020-2-2 |
| cake | 1 | 2019-3-2 |
| coca | 8 | 2020-3-6 |
| coca | 2 | 2020-5-10 |

The output should be something like this:

| Fname | GoodsCount | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cake | 3 | 2020-2-2 , 2019-3-2 |
| coca | 10 | 2020-3-6 , 2020-5-10 |

PS: I don't want to use `FOR XML PATH`

Comment: You can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: *"I should mention that i dont eant to use FOR XML PATH"* Why not? Note that if you're using an older version of SQL Server, that's the best way to create delimited data.

Answer (score 0):

Using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT 
   Fname, 
   SUM(Fcount) AS GoodsCount, 
   STRING_AGG(format(Dates,'y-M-d'),',') as Dates
FROM FoodSara_tbl T1
GROUP BY Fname, FID
```

Comment: Yes, the format should be changed to whatever you like most. `y` uses only 2 digits for the year, and `yyyy` uses 4 digits for the year.

Comment: I, personally, recommend `CONVERT` with a style code over `FORMAT`. The latter is not a very performant function.

Comment: @Larnu But this last parameter to CONVERT is really ....... (sorry i do not know the proper English word for it )

Comment: Is really, what, @Luuk ? Easy to reference? [Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: no, "easy" would mean that you can use "yyyy-mm-dd". "easy to reference" is an alias for Google.

Comment: Once you use it enough, you'll start to remember them anyway, @Luuk, but I disagree, it's it incredibly easy to reference.